# Remove arrays from nested arrays based on first element of each array

Tags: python, list

I have two nested arrays say

```
a=[[1,2,3],[2,4,7],[4,2,8],[3,5,7],[6,1,2]]
b=[[1,6,7],[2,4,9],[4,3,5],[3,10,2],[5,3,2],[7,2,1]]
```

I want to only keep those arrays in `b` whose first element is not common to the first elements of the arrays in `a`, so for these two we should get

```
c=[[5,3,2],[7,2,1]]
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may do like this,

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[2,4,7],[4,2,8],[3,5,7],[6,1,2]]
>>> b=[[1,6,7],[2,4,9],[4,3,5],[3,10,2],[5,3,2],[7,2,1]]
>>> [i for i in b if i[0] not in [j[0] for j in a]]
[[5, 3, 2], [7, 2, 1]]
>>>
```

or

```
>>> k = [j[0] for j in a]
>>> [i for i in b if i[0] not in k]
[[5, 3, 2], [7, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: You could use `any` to reduce the run time

Comment: Can you explain how above code will work? means which for loop with run first time or for every iteration on list b , we create `[j[0] for j in a]` list?

Comment: @VivekSable: Yes, the list comprehension `[j[0] for j in a]` gets re-built for every element in `b`, so this approach is quite inefficient. You can prove this by changing the list comp to `[f(j[0]) for j in a]`, where `f` is a function that prints & returns its argument. Avinash 2nd version doesn't have that defect, but it would be even better if `k` is a `set` or `frozenset`.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, yes 2nd approach will better. Set will improve performance better. Upvoted. +1

Comment: FWIW, a shorter way to create `k` is `zip(*a)[0]`. The result is a tuple, but that doesn't matter here. I don't know if it's faster than the list comp, though.

Answer (score 5):

To make this a little faster and efficient using `set`

**Code:**

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [2,4,7], [4,2,8], [3,5,7], [6,1,2]]
list2 = [[1,6,7], [2,4,9], [4,3,5], [3,10,2], [5,3,2], [7,2,1]]
check_set=set(val[0] for val in list1 )
print [val for val in list2 if val[0] not in check_set]
```

**Output:**

```
[[5, 3, 2], [7, 2, 1]]
```

**Notes:**

- First we are creating a set to store all the unique first value of list1
- The set is used to remove duplicate values at the same time member check in set is almost O(1) i.e.) 0 in `set([0,1,2]) is O(1)` member checking in list can go to a worst case of O(n)
- Finally creating a list by iterating over list2 and checking if the first element is not present in set

Comment: This is very fast and very efficient. Thank you!

Comment: @HuShu happy to help

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a homework problem, but I'm going to trust that this isn't one.

You can do this easily in two steps:

1. Store all first elements from `a` in a set.
2. Filter our lists in b whose first elements do not exist in the set.

   ```
   def remove_common(a, b):
      """remove lists from b whose first element is the first element of a list in a"""
      first_elements = set(sublist[0] for sublist in a)
      return list(filter(lambda sublist: sublist[0] not in first_elements, b))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

With dictionaries to enhance the data structure and garantees a linear complexity, assuming all l[0] are differents :

```
source,target={l[0]:l for l in a},{l[0]:l for l in b}
[target[key] for key in target.keys()-source.keys()]
```

Comment: Cute, although this technique isn't guaranteed to preserve order. But that may not be an issue. And of course this won't run on Python 2 (since in Python 2 `dict.keys()` returns a list) but that may not be an issue either. :)

Comment: In Python 2.7 subtraction is not working ` [1,2] - [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
`. This is working in `Python 3.x`

Answer (score 1):

You could assign `c` with a nested list comprehension.

```
c = [each_b for each_b in b if each_b[0] not in [each_a[0] for each_a in a]]
print(c)
>>> [[5, 3, 2], [7, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: @Avinish Raj beat me to the punch below :)